# Is there a compatible breaker fuse?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

The house I recently purchased has a fuse box (something I have never had before). I was hoping to use breaker fuses until I am able to get the box upgraded to breakers, however I don't know a lot about these and I am having a hard time finding compatible ones. I have attached a few images.

I am wondering if such a thing exists for this and where I could potentially find one?

[image][image]

Comment: Do you have a history of tripping breakers?

Comment: Whatever else you do, remember that breakers and fuses should not be blowing or tripping.  This is a sign of a problem - one you should not ignore, particularly with a convenient push-button reset breaker that makes it easy to just flip the power back on.  Is the house wired with knob and tube?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

I have seen these at Home Depot and a few other home stores. They are not cheap, about $10. I would be more concerned about why your fuses are blowing. Are the circuits overloaded? You need to determine that first. Don't even think about increasing the fuse/breaker size until you or someone else checks the wire size for the circuits. Just get a few boxes of the standard fuses and don't complicate things.

Comment: Precisely - you should have no need to constantly replace fuses - so a few spare, inexpensive fuses should hold you until you replace the box, or else you have problems that "breaker fuses" won't fix, and replacing the box (and otherwise fixing the circuits/wiring/capacity) is a high priority.

Comment: They were not constantly popping. My son was turning on a fireplace space heater that we don't usually use so the problem was solved. I really just wanted the breaker ones so that if they do pop while I am not at home I can tell my wife to just push the button in instead of looking for the right spare, etc.

Comment: @Ecnerwal: It's not uncommon to have circuits which will work fine provided that one doesn't try to e.g. run the toaster and microwave simultaneously, but would pop a fuse if one fails to wait for the toaster to pop before starting the microwave.  Having a push-button-resettable breaker would be much more convenient than a disposable fuse.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably what you are looking for.  Hopefully image comes thru.  I've never used them, so maybe others have an opinion about them.
[image]

Comment: yeah, except he want a 15A slow acting one...